# Unique jQuery function to update data from any table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function on a separate `functions.js` file, that is in charge of making a SQL update by posting some info. This is working properly, here you can see it:

Function being called on my php file, passing just element's ID info:

```
$('.tableContent').on('click', '.discontinueIcon', function() {
 turnId = $(this).attr('data-id');
 discontinueRow();})
```

Function working properly on a separate `functions.js` file:

```
function discontinueRow(){
    row = '#' + turnId;
    $.post('config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php', { tu_id:turnId }).success(messageOKKKK);}
```

---

---

As I will need to create many more functions updating info from many tables, I was trying to have a unique function, and provide it with needed info being sent with parameters from the php files. As I am new to this, do not even know if it is possible, and if it is I definitely can't get the way to.

I tried to store the needed values on several variables on my php file:

```
$('.tableContent').on('click', '.discontinueIcon', function() {
   turnId = $(this).attr('data-id');
   action = "'config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php'";
   elements = "tu_id:turnId";
   discontinueRow(action,elements);})
```

And using these parameters on the separate `functions.js` file as this shows:

```
function discontinueRow(action,elements){
    row = '#' + turnId;
    $.post(+action+,{ +elements+ }).success(messageOKKKK);}
```

But this does not work. Is it possible to pass by this way parameters to a function? In this case, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$('.tableContent').on('click', '.discontinueIcon', function() {
 turnId = $(this).attr('data-id');
 discontinueRow('config/forms/turn_conf/turn_discontinue.php', { tu_id:turnId });
});
```

you also need to set up your function with input parameters:

```
function discontinueRow(url, params){
    row = '#' + turnId;
    $.post(url, params).success(messageOKKKK);}
}
```

Comment: Worked. Very grateful Sergio.